# Make animation fade out using transition-duration

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, transition

I have created a button which transitions into a different colour when mouse hovers over. 
I cannot figure out how to make the colour change back to its original when the mouse is no longer hovering.

I have tried many ways, which have not worked.

Is there another Psuedo-element which I could use? Any help would be really appreciated.

```
#cta-btn:hover {
    background-color: #37A3BC;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s; 
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
 }
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue on jsfiddle or include more code here ? ... Works fine https://jsfiddle.net/6ph96m7m/

Comment: which browser are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the CSS I'm using and I've tested it against the latest browsers.

```
.team-member {
    padding: 15px; 
    background: #fafafa; 
    min-height: 150px; 
    width: 100%; 
    transition: linear background .5s; 
    border-radius: 3px; 
    overflow: auto; 

}
.team-member:hover { 
    background: #eee; 
    transition: linear background .5s;  
}
```

Also, you should also add vendor specific css prefix. For ex)

```
{
-moz-transition: linear background .5s; 
-o-transition: linear background .5s; 
-webkit-transition: linear background .5s; 
transition: linear background .5s;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to redefine `transition` in `:hover` if nothing changes.

Comment: Thanks very much! I had only added transition properties to the hover class.

Comment: you're absolutely correct Blaze. I'll put some time in refactoring my css.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your original cta-btn:

```
#cta-btn {
background-color: (enter your original bg color) ;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s; 
transition-duration: 0.5s;
 }
```